# View state is not getting in the Page PreInit event

Tags: asp.net

Hii,,

I need a help. I have a master page and i am changing the masterpage file property to some other master page dynamically in the page PreInit event and that changing url is taken from a viewstate. but the view state is not getting in the pre init event. If you finding any solution regarding this pls help me....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The viewstate is not available in the PreInit event. You'll need to use something else, such as URL parameters to determine which master page to use. It's better to have separate URLs for different views anyways.

Answer (score 0):

try this: `session("somename")` ?